SpringBoot:MissingServletRequestParameterException:Required request parameter 'itemId' for method parameter type Long is present but converted to null
I am trying to create an application in Spring Boot. I am defining the methods updateBasket and removeItem but they seem to be having issues. When I ran the project, and in the form when I click let's say "Update Quantity" it threw me a Whitelabel error, saying Bad request type, status 400. Tomcat server logs shows:
"Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'itemId' for method parameter type Long is present but converted to null]"
package com.example.test1.controller;

import com.example.test1.model.Beverage;
import com.example.test1.model.OrderItem;
import com.example.test1.model.Order;
import com.example.test1.service.BeverageService;
import com.example.test1.service.OrderItemService;
import com.example.test1.service.OrderService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
// Import the HttpServletRequest

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
public class BasketController {

    @Autowired
    private BeverageService beverageService;

    @Autowired
    private OrderItemService orderItemService;

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping("/basket")
    public String showBasket(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        // Retrieve the basket from the session
        List<OrderItem> basket = (List<OrderItem>) session.getAttribute("basket");

        // If the basket is null (i.e., no items in the basket), initialize it
        if (basket == null) {
            basket = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // Calculate the total price
        double totalPrice = 0;
        for (OrderItem item : basket) {
            totalPrice += item.getPrice();
        }

        // Add the basket and the total price to the model so it can be accessed in the Thymeleaf template
        model.addAttribute("items", basket);
        model.addAttribute("totalPrice", totalPrice);

        // Return the name of the Thymeleaf template to render
        return "basket";  // This refers to the "basket.html" template
    }

    // Add beverage to basket
    // BasketController.java
    @PostMapping("/add-to-basket")
    public String addToBasket(@RequestParam Long beverageId, HttpSession session) {
        Beverage beverage = beverageService.getBeverageById(beverageId);

        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
        orderItem.setBeverage(beverage);
        orderItem.setPrice(beverage.getPrice());

        // Retrieve the current basket from the session or create a new one
        List<OrderItem> basket = (List<OrderItem>) session.getAttribute("basket");
        if (basket == null) {
            basket = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // Add the new OrderItem to the basket
        basket.add(orderItem);

        // Save the updated basket back into the session
        session.setAttribute("basket", basket);

        return "redirect:/basket";  // Redirect to the basket page to view the updated contents
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit-order")
    public String submitOrder(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        List<OrderItem> basket = (List<OrderItem>) session.getAttribute("basket");

        if (basket != null && !basket.isEmpty()) {
            // Create a new Order and set total price, etc.
            Order order = new Order();
            double totalPrice = 0;
            for (OrderItem item : basket) {
                totalPrice += item.getPrice(); // Calculate total price for the basket
            }
            order.setPrice(totalPrice); // Set the price of the order

            // Save the order
            orderService.saveOrder(order);

            // Associate OrderItems with the Order
            for (OrderItem item : basket) {
                item.setOrder(order); // Link each item to the order
                orderItemService.saveOrderItem(item); // Save the OrderItem
            }

            // Remove the basket from the session
            session.removeAttribute("basket");

            // Add order details to the model for the confirmation page
            model.addAttribute("totalPrice", totalPrice);  // Pass total price to the view
            model.addAttribute("orderItems", basket);  // Pass order items to the view
        }

        return "order-confirmation"; // Redirect to the order confirmation page
    }

    @PostMapping("/update-basket")
    public String updateBasket(@RequestParam Long itemId, @RequestParam int quantity, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Debugging: Print received itemId and quantity
        System.out.println("Received itemId: " + itemId + ", quantity: " + quantity);

        // Invalidate the current session and create a new one to avoid any session inconsistencies
        session.invalidate(); // Clears the current session
        session = request.getSession(true); // Creates a new session

        // Retrieve the basket from session
        List<OrderItem> basket = (List<OrderItem>) session.getAttribute("basket");

        if (basket != null && !basket.isEmpty()) {
            // Look for the OrderItem by id
            for (OrderItem item : basket) {
                System.out.println("Checking item with ID: " + item.getId());

                if (item.getId() != null && item.getId().equals(itemId)) {
                    // Found the correct item, update its quantity and price
                    item.setQuantity(quantity);
                    item.setPrice(item.getBeverage().getPrice() * quantity);

                    // Debugging: print updated item details
                    System.out.println("Updated item: " + item.getId() + ", Quantity: " + item.getQuantity() + ", Price: " + item.getPrice());
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Save the updated basket back into the session
            session.setAttribute("basket", basket);
        }

        // Redirect back to the basket page to reflect the changes
        return "redirect:/basket";
    }

    @PostMapping("/remove-item")
    public String removeItem(@RequestParam Long itemId, HttpSession session) {
        List<OrderItem> basket = (List<OrderItem>) session.getAttribute("basket");
        if (basket != null) {
            basket.removeIf(item -> item.getId().equals(itemId)); // Remove item by itemId
            session.setAttribute("basket", basket); // Save updated basket in session
        }
        return "redirect:/basket"; // Redirect back to basket page
    }
}

This is the BasketController.java file where I am defining the logic.
basket.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Basket</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your Basket</h1>

<!-- Empty Basket Check -->
<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(items)}">
    <p>Your basket is empty. Add some beverages to your basket first.</p>
</div>

<!-- Display Items -->
<

<!-- Loop through each item in the basket -->
Basket.html Form
Ensure your form is correctly structured. Specifically, ensure that the input fields for itemId and quantity are correctly named and bound:

html
Copy code
<div th:each="item : ${items}">
    <p th:text="'Beverage: ' + ${item.beverage.name}"></p>
    <p th:text="'Price: €' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(item.price, 2, 1)}"></p>
    <p th:text="'Volume: ' + ${item.beverage.volume} + 'L'"></p>

    <!-- Form to update quantity -->
    <form action="/update-basket" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:value="${item.id}" name="itemId" /> <!-- Ensure itemId is passed -->
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" th:value="${item.quantity}" min="1" />
        <button type="submit">Update Quantity</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Form to remove item -->
    <form action="/remove-item" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:value="${item.id}" name="itemId" />
        <button type="submit">Remove</button>
    </form>
</div>


<!-- Display Total Price -->
<div>
    <p th:text="'Total Price: €' + ${#numbers.formatDecimal(totalPrice, 2, 1)}"></p>
</div>
<!-- Submit Order Button -->
<form action="/submit-order" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

and the OrderItem.java model class:
package com.example.test1.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String position;

    private double price;

    private int quantity = 1; // Default quantity

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "beverage_id")
    private Beverage beverage; // This is the reference to the Beverage entity

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order; // The order to which this item belongs

    // Getters and Setters

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price * quantity; // Return price based on quantity
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Beverage getBeverage() {
        return beverage;
    }

    public void setBeverage(Beverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order; // Set the order for the order item
    }
}

There are also some other model classes and controllers in my project but I think for understanding the problem these should be sufficient. Why the id is being returned as null?

The OrderItems in your basket don't have IDs assigned when they're created. But when you try to update or remove items, you're looking for items by their ID, but these IDs are null. ID is not being auto generated as you are not using database.

I am using the H2 database.
this is the applications.properties file:
`# Enable H2 console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
In-memory database configuration (Spring Boot should automatically set this)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
Dialect for H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
server.servlet.session.timeout=15m
`
